# STL function minimum observation

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I am building a forecasting model sing R utilizing `stl()` function. I have monthly data for 2 years, that's 24 observations, 2 period.

Now `stl()` won't allow me to decompose my data saying that I have less than the required minimum observation. I check the code and yes, it needs to be 24 + 1 or 2 period + 1.

My question is why it needs extra observation? `decompose()` function needs only at least 2 period.

Comment: thanks @G.Grothendieck. I already edited it. thanks.

Comment: The best course of action would perhaps be to wait for more data. If this is all the data available to you, then you might encounter difficulties estimating, and verifying the accuracy of your model due to the short train/test sets. [This article/paper](https://robjhyndman.com/papers/shortseasonal.pdf) discusses minimum sample size for seasonal forecasting. Perhaps it can be enlightening.

Comment: Hi @henrik_ibsen, thanks for responding. I know having more data is good, but my question is really on the difference of the code of `stl()` and `decompose()` function in R. how sir @rob, the author can enlighten us.