# Tibble Not Working to Get Date For Anomaly Detection (Reproducible Example)

Tags: r, tidyverse, tibble

I have a dataset below:

```
dput(stack)

structure(list(Day = structure(c(17836, 17837, 17838, 17840, 
17840, 17841, 17842, 17843, 17843, 17843, 17844, 17844, 17844, 
17845, 17845, 17845, 17846, 17846, 17847, 17847, 17847, 17848, 
17848, 17848, 17849, 17849, 17850, 17850, 17850, 17850, 17851, 
17851, 17851, 17851, 17852, 17852, 17852, 17852, 17853, 17853, 
17853, 17853, 17854, 17854, 17854, 17854, 17855, 17855, 17855, 
17855, 17856, 17856, 17856, 17856, 17857, 17857, 17857, 17857, 
17858, 17858, 17858, 17858, 17859, 17859, 17859, 17859, 17860, 
17860, 17860, 17860, 17860, 17861, 17861, 17861, 17861, 17862, 
17862, 17862, 17862, 17863, 17863, 17863, 17863, 17864, 17864, 
17864, 17864, 17865, 17865, 17865, 17865, 17866, 17866, 17866, 
17866, 17867, 17867, 17867, 17867, 17868, 17868, 17868, 17868, 
17869, 17869, 17869, 17869, 17869, 17870, 17870, 17870, 17870, 
17871, 17871, 17871, 17871, 17871, 17871, 17871, 17872, 17872, 
17872, 17872, 17872, 17872, 17872, 17873, 17873, 17873, 17873, 
17873, 17873, 17874, 17874, 17874, 17874, 17874, 17874, 17875, 
17875, 17875, 17875, 17875, 17875, 17876, 17876, 17876, 17876, 
17876, 17876, 17877, 17877, 17877, 17877, 17877, 17877, 17878, 
17878, 17878, 17878, 17878, 17878), class = "Date"), Channel = c("D", 
"A", "D", "A", "D", "D", "D", "A", "B", "D", "A", "B", "D", "A", 
"B", "D", "A", "D", "A", "B", "D", "A", "D", "G", "A", "D", "A", 
"D", "F", "G", "A", "D", "F", "G", "A", "D", "F", "G", "A", "D", 
"F", "G", "A", "D", "F", "G", "A", "D", "F", "G", "A", "D", "F", 
"G", "A", "D", "F", "G", "A", "D", "F", "G", "A", "D", "F", "G", 
"A", "B", "D", "F", "G", "A", "D", "F", "G", "A", "D", "F", "G", 
"A", "D", "F", "G", "A", "D", "F", "G", "A", "D", "F", "G", "A", 
"D", "F", "G", "A", "D", "F", "G", "A", "D", "F", "G", "A", "D", 
"E", "F", "G", "A", "D", "F", "G", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", 
"G", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "A", "C", "D", "E", "F", 
"G", "A", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "A", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", 
"A", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "A", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "A", 
"C", "D", "E", "F", "G"), Orders = c(0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 36, 0, 1, 46, 1, 11, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 112, 0, 66, 
1, 765, 2, 133, 0, 2290, 9, 524, 2, 6417, 8, 33, 0, 1008, 7, 
70, 1, 1860, 12, 62, 3, 1141, 12, 67, 5, 1059, 13, 14, 2, 481, 
13, 84, 6, 1693, 23, 370, 16, 6028, 51, 29, 0, 3, 640, 11, 5, 
0, 569, 12, 31, 2, 730, 16, 45, 4, 961, 27, 71, 2, 594, 55, 155, 
10, 607, 48, 224, 30, 4298, 66, 50, 0, 587, 92, 27, 1, 728, 80, 
195, 3, 0, 1310, 62, 24, 6, 754, 46, 18, 0, 0, 2, 0, 439, 50, 
107, 0, 0, 7, 0, 981, 55, 130, 0, 11, 0, 2784, 83, 61, 0, 4, 
0, 843, 77, 110, 0, 0, 0, 885, 63, 70, 0, 3, 0, 481, 77, 81, 
0, 0, 0, 833, 83, 38, 0, 1, 1, 712, 88)), row.names = c(NA, -162L
), spec = structure(list(cols = list(Day = structure(list(), class = 
c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Channel = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Orders = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector"))), class = "col_spec"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Below are the first few rows:

```
head(stack)
 # A tibble: 6 x 3
   Day        Channel Orders
   <date>     <chr>    <dbl>
 1 2018-11-01 D            0
 2 2018-11-02 A            0
 3 2018-11-03 D            0
 4 2018-11-05 A            2
 5 2018-11-05 D            0
 6 2018-11-06 D            0
```

I want to use the anomalize package to see the anomalies by group.

Based on the reference below, I want to plot each performance by group
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/anomalize/versions/0.1.1

This is my attempt with the dataset I provided.

```
stack %>%
  # Data Manipulation / Anomaly Detection
  time_decompose(Orders, method = "stl") %>%
  anomalize(remainder, method = "iqr") %>%
  time_recompose() %>%
  # Anomaly Visualization
  plot_anomalies(time_recomposed = TRUE, ncol = 3, alpha_dots = 0.25) +
  labs(title = "Tidyverse Anomalies", subtitle = "STL + IQR Methods")
```

Here is my error:

```
Converting from tbl_df to tbl_time.
Auto-index message: index = Day
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: Only year, quarter, month, week, and day periods are 
allowed for an index of class Date.
```

Expected output should be something like this based on the website reference:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your date variable is not unique.

```
all(length(unique(stack$Day))==length(stack$Day))
```

Time decomposition failed because the data is not an equal interval time-series

```
Evaluation error: Only year, quarter, month, week, and day periods are 
allowed for an index of class Date.
```

We know the error is from `time_decompose` because the error first arises following that line of code:

```
stack %>%
    # Data Manipulation / Anomaly Detection
    time_decompose(Orders, method = "stl") 

Converting from tbl_df to tbl_time.
Auto-index message: index = Day
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: Only year, quarter, month, week, and day periods are allowed for an index of class Date.
```

When we `group_by` by day and sum the values in the `Orders` variable we obtain unique intervals of time. The code shows no errors:

```
stack %>%
  group_by(Day) %>%
  summarise(Orders = sum(Orders)) %>%
  time_decompose(Orders, method = "stl") %>%
  anomalize(remainder, method = "iqr") %>%
  time_recompose() %>%
  # Anomaly Visualization
  plot_anomalies(time_recomposed = TRUE, ncol = 3, alpha_dots = 0.25)
```

I suspect you want the time-series by `Channel`. If that's the case, you will face some problems because there isn't enough data to decompose trends for each channel. Channels B, C, and E cannot be decomposed. See code below:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
a<-stack %>%
  filter(Channel=="A") %>%
  group_by(Day) %>%
  summarise(Orders=sum(Orders)) %>% #in case of repeat dates
  time_decompose(Orders, method = "stl") %>%
  anomalize(remainder, method = "iqr") %>%
  time_recompose() %>%
  plot_anomalies(time_recomposed = TRUE, ncol = 3, alpha_dots = 0.25) +
  labs(title = "Tidyverse Anomalies", subtitle = "STL + IQR Methods")
```

No problems with a. Now lets inspect b:

```
b<-stack %>%
  filter(Channel=="B") %>%
  group_by(Day) %>%
  summarise(Orders=sum(Orders)) %>%
  time_decompose(Orders, method = "stl") %>%
  anomalize(remainder, method = "iqr") %>%
  time_recompose() %>%
  plot_anomalies(time_recomposed = TRUE, ncol = 3, alpha_dots = 0.25) +
  labs(title = "Tidyverse Anomalies", subtitle = "STL + IQR Methods")

Converting from tbl_df to tbl_time.
Auto-index message: index = Day
frequency = 1.5 weeks
trend = 7 weeks
Error in stats::stl(., s.window = "periodic", t.window = trnd, robust = TRUE) : 
  series is not periodic or has less than two periods
```

The error tells us everything. Lets see how long b

```
b
# A tibble: 7 x 3
  Day        Channel Orders
  <date>     <chr>    <dbl>
1 2018-11-08 B            0
2 2018-11-09 B            0
3 2018-11-10 B            0
4 2018-11-12 B            0
5 2018-11-25 B            0
6 2018-12-06 B            0
7 2018-12-07 B            0
```

Thats only 7 observations. Not enough for a trend

```
c<-stack %>%
  filter(Channel=="C") %>%
  group_by(Day) %>%
  summarise(Orders=sum(Orders)) %>%
  time_decompose(Orders, method = "stl") %>%
  anomalize(remainder, method = "iqr") %>%
  time_recompose() %>%
  plot_anomalies(time_recomposed = TRUE, ncol = 3, alpha_dots = 0.25) +
  labs(title = "Tidyverse Anomalies", subtitle = "STL + IQR Methods")
```

Same for c. Now lets see d, e, f, and g.

```
d<-stack %>%
  filter(Channel=="D") %>%
  group_by(Day) %>%
  summarise(Orders=sum(Orders)) %>%
  time_decompose(Orders, method = "stl") %>%
  anomalize(remainder, method = "iqr") %>%
  time_recompose() %>%
  plot_anomalies(time_recomposed = TRUE, ncol = 3, alpha_dots = 0.25) +
  labs(title = "Tidyverse Anomalies", subtitle = "STL + IQR Methods")
e<-stack %>%
  filter(Channel=="E") %>%
  group_by(Day) %>%
  summarise(Orders=sum(Orders)) %>%
  time_decompose(Orders, method = "stl") %>%
  anomalize(remainder, method = "iqr") %>%
  time_recompose() %>%
  plot_anomalies(time_recomposed = TRUE, ncol = 3, alpha_dots = 0.25) +
  labs(title = "Tidyverse Anomalies", subtitle = "STL + IQR Methods")
f<-stack %>%
  filter(Channel=="F") %>%
  group_by(Day) %>%
  summarise(Orders=sum(Orders)) %>%
  time_decompose(Orders, method = "stl") %>%
  anomalize(remainder, method = "iqr") %>%
  time_recompose() %>%
  plot_anomalies(time_recomposed = TRUE, ncol = 3, alpha_dots = 0.25) +
  labs(title = "Tidyverse Anomalies", subtitle = "STL + IQR Methods")
g<-stack %>%
  filter(Channel=="G") %>%
  group_by(Day) %>%
  summarise(Orders=sum(Orders)) %>%
  time_decompose(Orders, method = "stl") %>%
  anomalize(remainder, method = "iqr") %>%
  time_recompose() %>%
  plot_anomalies(time_recomposed = TRUE, ncol = 3, alpha_dots = 0.25) +
  labs(title = "Tidyverse Anomalies", subtitle = "STL + IQR Methods")
```

Only Channels a,d,f,g have enough observations to decompose trend.

```
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(a,d,f,g, nrow=2)
```

[image]

You can also accomplish the above using a single line of code (I just wanted to explain why the errors were being generated).

```
stack %>%
  filter(Channel=="A"| Channel=="D"|Channel=="F"|Channel=="G") %>%
  group_by(Channel) %>%
  time_decompose(Orders, method = "stl") %>%
  anomalize(remainder, method = "iqr") %>%
  time_recompose() %>%
  plot_anomalies(time_recomposed = TRUE, ncol = 2, alpha_dots = 0.25) +
  labs(title = "Tidyverse Anomalies", subtitle = "STL + IQR Methods")
```

[image]

Comment: This is amazing thank you! I'm definitely accepting this. I have one other question to make this more automated - is there a minimum amount of observations per group that would allow the data to have a trend? My actual dataset had many groups and I would rather say ex: min=14 observations rather than hardcoding it

Comment: That's a ? of theory. `time_decompose(method='stl')` uses LOESS smoothing. There need to be enough values across 2 time periods to produce reliable estimates via local regression. So what you're really asking is what the min # of observations needed to produce reliable estimates are. I'm not sure. There is a specific #  for the STL implementation of this package but that does not answer the more fundamental question. Even if you can get it to time decompose the data, would you trust the results? See this discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48723342/stl-function-minimum-observation

Comment: Thanks, will read more into it from the link you provided. Really appreciate all the help